# update data in vb oledb

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio, oledb

i'm gonna straight forward. i have these lines of codes. basically it's about update data based on user input. but first, the textbox will retrieve data from database, and then the user will be free to change the value/text of the textbox and when the user click a button, the system will store the new value to database.

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim check As String = Session("user_id")

    Dim SqlSelect As String = "SELECT * FROM Worker Where user_id='" & check & "' "
    Dim con As dbConn = New dbConn()
    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(SqlSelect, con.oleconnection)
    Dim reader As OleDbDataReader

    Try
        con.open()
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        reader.Read()
        WorkerID_.Text = reader("WorkerID").ToString()
        WorkerName.Text = reader("WorkerName").ToString()
        DoB.Text = reader("DoB").ToString()
        Address.Text = reader("Address").ToString()
        Phone.Text = reader("Phone").ToString()
        Email.Text = reader("Email").ToString()
        Company.Text = reader("CompanyName").ToString()
        PassNum.Text = reader("PassportNum").ToString()
        PassExp.Text = reader("PassportExp").ToString()
        VisaExp.Text = reader("VisaExp").ToString()
    Finally
        reader.Close()
        con.close()
    End Try

End Sub

Protected Sub Update_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim con As dbConn = New dbConn()
    Dim SqlUpdate As String

    SqlUpdate = "UPDATE Worker SET "
    SqlUpdate &= "WorkerID = '" & WorkerID_.Text & "', "
    SqlUpdate &= "WorkerName = '" & WorkerName.Text & "', "
    SqlUpdate &= "Address = '" & Address.Text & "', "
    SqlUpdate &= "Email = '" & Email.Text & "', "
    SqlUpdate &= "CompanyName = '" & Company.Text & "', "
    SqlUpdate &= "PassportNum = '" & PassNum.Text & "' "
    SqlUpdate &= "Where user_id ='" & Session("user_id") & "'"

    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(SqlUpdate, con.oleconnection)
    Dim rad As OleDbDataReader

    Try
        con.open()
        rad = cmd.ExecuteReader()

    Finally
        rad.Close()
        con.close()
        Response.Redirect("~\Worker\Profile.aspx")
    End Try
End Sub
```

based on this code, the data can't be updated. the textbox.text in update_click will retrieve the same value of textbox in page_load (which is data from database) instead of the text input by the user.

it all worked fine if i delete the code for retrieving the data from database inside page_load.  did i miss something in my code?

Comment: i've solved it. i forgot to check if it's postback or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put

```
If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
     //code
End If
```

inside page_load